# How to assign *multiple* foreground service types to one Android service

Tags: android, foreground-service, android-11

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element) states

> android:foregroundServiceType
>
> Specify that the service is a foreground service that satisfies a particular use case. For example, a foreground service type of "location" indicates that an app is getting the device's current location, usually to continue a user-initiated action related to device location.
>
> **You can assign multiple foreground service types to a particular service.**

**Question**

How can I specify multiple types in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

**Current state**

So far I declare the foreground service to use the [camera](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/foreground-services) type:

```
<application>
  <service
      android:name=".BackgroundService"
      android:exported="false"
      android:foregroundServiceType="camera"
      android:process=":camera_process" />
</application>
```

But as I have to geo-reference the images captured by the camera, I also have to declare the `foregroundServiceType="location"`.

**I can easily reference both types in the Java code** as requested [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo#FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA):

> Constant corresponding to camera in the R.attr.foregroundServiceType attribute. Use the camera device or record video. For apps with targetSdkVersion Build.VERSION_CODES.R and above, a foreground service will not be able to access the camera if this type is not specified in the manifest **and in Service.startForeground(int, android.app.Notification, int)**.

By using this flag:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,  PlaceholderNotificationBuilder.build(this), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MANIFEST);
} else {
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, PlaceholderNotificationBuilder.build(this));
}
```

But how to declare both `foregroundServiceType`s in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 10):

I found the hint on [another documentation site](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#loc-camera) after some searching:

```
<manifest>
...
<service ... android:foregroundServiceType="location|camera" />
```